# Optimizing performance of subqueries

Tags: mysql, query

I am fairly new to MySQL and I am trying to return a result of a query based on a subquery, but I notice very poor performence.

This is the statement I wrote:

```
SELECT value 
FROM `history_text` 
WHERE itemid = (SELECT itemid 
                FROM `items` 
                WHERE name regexp "^.*hrcm1k45e7o2xvyl.*IP.*Address"
                ) 
ORDER BY clock DESC limit 1;
```

However, I notice it takes around 4 seconds to execute this query, whereas if I split it into two, it takes only about 1 second to execute both queries:

```
SELECT itemid 
FROM `items` 
WHERE name regexp "^.*hrcm1k45e7o2xvyl.*IP.*Address";

SELECT value 
FROM `history_text` 
WHERE itemid="48074" 
ORDER BY clock DESC limit 1;
```

Performance is very important to me in this use case, why are the split queries so much faster and how can I optimize my single query?

Comment: The first query will produce an error if more than one value is returned by the subquery, might consider change it to `in`. In the first query there is no `WHERE itemid="48074"` condition

Comment: Please provide table description (run `show create table history_text` and `show create table items`) and execution plan (run explain before your query)

Comment: Problem 1: Searching for text in the middle of columns.  Problem 2: Use JOIN instead of a subquery or two queries.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT value 
FROM `history_text` 
JOIN ( SELECT itemid 
       FROM `items` 
       WHERE name regexp "^.*hrcm1k45e7o2xvyl.*IP.*Address"
       ) AS criteria USING (itemid)
ORDER BY clock DESC limit 1;
```

or

```sql
SELECT value 
FROM `history_text` 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM `items` 
               WHERE name regexp "^.*hrcm1k45e7o2xvyl.*IP.*Address"
                 AND items.itemid = history_text.itemid
               ) 
ORDER BY clock DESC limit 1;
```

Which option will be faster depends on the data statistics.